# Recovering tweets with media using tweepy

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

i'm having problem with the twitter api. I used this script [Script to delete tweets](https://gist.github.com/davej/113241)
To delete the tweets form an account. I see that tweepy method (api,user_timeline) at

```
 for status in tweepy.Cursor(api.user_timeline).items():
           try:
```

will not return those tweets that contain media (accessing twitter from the website they don't show up in the timeline but in another tab called 'photos and videos') so they are not deleted. include_entities is not a parameter for this method.

how can i recover these tweets? I thought i could searching with the username as query, but that doesn't work and could be very inefficient.

is there another method on the twitter API or a parameter that's not included with the documentation?

Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 0):

I found that this is a problem twitter has when erasing massively tweets. Nothing we can do for now!